# Dell Inspirion 7591 on-board microphone not found 18.04 LTS

Tags: dell, microphone

Dell Inspirion 7591 touch screen workstation.  Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.  The onboard microphone is not found; an external USB microphone works.  Is there a fix to find the built-in microphone and configure it so that it works with Zoom?  Take care.  Stay safe.

Comment: Can you open that app `Additional Drivers` and see if any are available? Also any information you can find about the internal microphone would be nice.

Comment: https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-General/Dell-drivers-or-utilities-for-Ubuntu-Linux-18-04/td-p/7258092   Re: Dell drivers or utilities for Ubuntu Linux 18.04?

Dell does have some things.

HOWEVER

These are not for all Dells All models

and support is not free.  Redhat and Ubuntu support tend to be for Enterprise customers with a support contract.  End web excerpt.  Does Ubuntu license for fee the needed driver?  Dell will not because the model under discussion is only available with MS Win 10 pre-installed (Ubuntu pre-installed with drivers is outside USA).

Comment: @Pixelated Fish How does one find "Additional Drivers"?  I can upload the PDF of the technical repair manual for the machine, or other such material -- is there an Ubuntu CLI command or GUI that will list the hardware whether or not there is a driver (SL did have this).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I was thinking of Ubuntu 20.04. You need to open "Software & Updates," and go to the driver tab (that's all the Additional Drivers application does.)

Comment: I did as you suggested; the only additional drivers that were displayed were nvidia (already installed) and an Intel video/graphics driver (not used -- nvidia used instead).  No on-board microphone input.  The machine is Ubuntu certified, but the proprietary Dell version that was so certified is not available in the USA it seems -- Dell USA has been totally unresponsive, and Dell outside the USA is precluded from assisting with user requests from the USA.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to get the internal microphone on a Dell Inspiron 7591 working with the following steps:

1. Create /etc/modprobe.d/sof-blacklists.conf with the following:

> ```
> blacklist snd-hda-intel
> blacklist snd-soc-skl
> ```

2. Create the ~/.config/pulse/default.pa with the following:

> ```
> .include /etc/pulse/default.pa
> load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,6 source_name=mic1
> update-source-proplist mic1 device.description="Internal Microphone 48kHz"
> load-module module-alsa-source device=hw:0,7 source_name=mic2
> update-source-proplist mic2 device.description="Internal Microphone 16kHz"
> set-default-source mic1
> ```

3. Find and build (if needed) and install the firmware-sof-signed package.
4. Install the appropriate ALSA UCM files:

> ```
> $ git clone https://github.com/thesofproject/alsa-ucm-conf.git
> $ cd alsa-ucm-conf
> $ git checkout -b inspiron f083700
> $ sudo cp -r ucm/sof-skl_hda_card /usr/share/alsa/ucm/
> ```

5. Reboot, login, the microphone should work.

Comment: You state Find and build (if needed) and install the firmware-sof-signed package .  Where (URL or changes/additions to ```Software & Updates Configuration```) does one find this package and what steps are needed to build it?  Most .deb files from Ubuntu repositories are ready to install, or have building "taken care of" during the install.